# How can we define event time and process time , while defining table from data stream on flink over version 1.16

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

At Flink 1.16 version , StreamTableEnvironment.fromDataStream(DataStream dataStream, Expression... fields) method is depricated.

At previous versions, it can be defined by using expressions event time and process time by methods

.rowtime() ,

.proctime() ,
as defined in https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/table/concepts/time_attributes/

What is the right methodology in newly releases?

At previous version we can define table from stream as

```
Table transactionTable = tableEnv.fromDataStream(transactionDataStream,$("Field1"),$("field2"),$("field3")
        ,$("transactionTime").rowtime(),$("ts").proctime());
```

but the method StreamTableEnvironment.fromDataStream(DataStream dataStream, Expression... fields) is depricated after version 1.15

Answer (score 0):

You should now use `<T> Table fromDataStream(DataStream<T> dataStream, Schema schema)` instead, where the Schema will be something like this:

```java
Schema.newBuilder()
    .column("field1", DataTypes.INT())
    .column("transactionTime", DataTypes.TIMESTAMP_LTZ(3))
    .columnByExpression("ts", "PROCTIME()")
    .watermark("transactionTime", "transactionTime - INTERVAL '10' SECOND"")
    .build();
```

There's more information, and more examples, [in the documentation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/table/data_stream_api).